# Best method for storing multiple ID's in MySQL for querying large result sets

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to save which email lists a client subscribes to. I might have:

email_lists:

```
ID    Name
1     Coupons
2     Monthly Newsletter
3     Company News
```

Now, users can subscribe to as many lists as they want. So let's say I have three users:

users:

```
ID    Name    Lists
1     Bob     1,3
2     Jane    2,3
3     Tom     1
```

Now I need to do a query to get all user ID's which are subscribed to list #1:

```
SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Lists LIKE '%1%'
```

Is there a better way of storing the list ID's for each user where queries can be performed more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third table `subscrib` would be the best here:

```
UserId    ListId
1         1      // Bob, Coupons
1         3      // Bob, Company news
2         2      // Jane, Monthly Newsletter
2         3      // Jane, Company news
3         1      // Tom, Coupons
```

And then your query would be something like (for `Company news`):

```
SELECT UserId FROM subscrib WHERE ListId = '3';
```

Or

```
SELECT s.ListId, u.Email, u.Name FROM subscrib s
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.ID = s.UserId
WHERE s.ListId = '3';
```